# can not able to play mp3 files in android development

Tags: android

here i am trying to play an mp3 file located in sdcard/music/audioex.m4a but its not playing any sound. here is my code and i am also getting a warning says"MediaPlayer finalized without being released"

```
package com.example.me.audioplay;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
       try{
           Toast.makeText(this,Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           mp.setDataSource("Music/audioex.m4a");
           mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
           mp.prepare();
           mp.start();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Playing an mp3 from internal",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }catch (Exception e)
       {e.printStackTrace();

       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Data source make sure its absolute file path. Below datasource is wrong.

```
mp.setDataSource("Music/audioex.m4a");
```

I think you need this as below.

```
File musicDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator++"music/audioex.m4a");
```

Comment: How about this? mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Music/audioex.m4a"); 
and it is still not working

Comment: where u have put your music file. Please check do you have proper permissins or not in android manifest

Comment: i also added this permission in manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: yeah.. permission is needed

Comment: check upadated ans